# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a Ruby on Rails project with docker and I don't understand how to make this stuff working probably because I'm not familiar with docker.
I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, since now:

- I've installed `docker`
- I've installed `docker-compose`
- I've run `docker-compose build` which runs successfully
- but `docker-compose run --rm web bin/setup` stops because it cannot
  connect to mysql server

The error I get is:

```
#<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"root", "password"=>"root", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000,  "database"=>"project"}, {}
Created database 'project'
rails aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Looking here of stackoverflow many says I have to be sure the mysql server is running. How can i do this? The result of `docker ps` is the following (omitted the COMMAND ans CREATED columns)

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE        STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
9f03056e2b54        project_web  Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3035->3035/tcp             project_webpack
465cfbac7cbd        mysql        Up About an hour    3306/tcp                           project_mysql
```

My `database.yml`:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: root
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: project_local

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &test
  <<: *default
  database: project_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3

staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: <MY HOST>
  database: project_dev
  username: root
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: project_web
    container_name: project_web
    # restart: always
    command: >
      ./wait-for-it.sh db:3306 -- bash -c "
        rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0 --pid /app/tmp/pids/server.pid
        "
    ports: ["3000:3000"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ~/tmp:/host_tmp
      - bundle_cache:/bundle
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_USERNAME=root
      - DB_PASSWORD=root
  db:
    container_name: project_mysql
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
volumes:
  bundle_cache:
  # Mount volume with default driver
```

Comment: Instead of using host "localhost", use "mysql"

Comment: SSH into your server and run `sudo find / -type s` to see where your mysql socket is located and see if it matches `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running docker-compose try to run the container itself:

```
docker run --rm -it mysql-server:latest bash
```

this should  give you a normal shell environment inside the container. from there you can try mysql, configure your server, start or stop it and everthing else you can do on a "normal" linux.

ps: if you need mor tools try apt-get update and then install what your need.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I still don't understand what I should change

Comment: did you run my command? did you check that your mysql server is running? have you exposed the server (/etc/my.ini -> bind-address=0.0.0.0)? can you connect from your ubuntu machine to it using the ip-address of the container and a normal mysql command?

Comment: Your command runs well but I had to add `sudo`. I can connect to it with `mysql -u root -p -h 172.18.0.2`

Comment: do you connect from your ubuntu machine? if yes, you allready have your solution: you have to change the setup to the ip address from above. otherwise try to connect from your ubuntu. if that fails to mysql does not accept connections from outside the container. that would be the point where your have to change the bind-address.

Comment: I've changed the host in the `database.yml` to be `db` and not `localhost` and everything went good

Answer (score 2):

Try to change in your database.yml the host to 0.0.0.0 This solved my problem.

In the context of servers, 0.0.0.0 means all IPv4 addresses on the local machine. If a host has two IP addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable at both of those IPs.

Answer (score 0):

With a similar `docker-compose.yml`, my solution was to remove the named volume that is defined in the `db` service:

```
$ docker volume ls # confirm the named volume is present
DRIVER      VOLUME_NAME
local       db-data

$ docker-compose down # stop/remove your containers for this project

$ docker volume rm db-data # remove the (possibly) problematic volume

$ docker-compose up # start the project in the foreground and hopefully not see the socket connection error in the logs
```